# How do I print words that are the same in two sentences in python?

Tags: python, list

5a. Prompt the user to enter 2 sentences, called sen1 and sen2

5b. Print all the words that are in both sentences

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion or code writing service. We're glad to help once you've made an effort to do something yourself and run into difficulties. If you can't get started on your assignment, ask the instructor who gave it to you for help. If it's not homework, find a tutorial (there's one at http://www.python.org that isn't bad). Before posting your next question here, you should spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, particularly [ask]. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I misunderstand your question at first.
This is the corrected version. 
(PS: I did not consider the sentence initial situation, you may use lower() function to correct the code yourself.

```
def main():
    sen1 = input('Please enter sentence 1:')
    sen2 = input('Please enter sentence 2:')
    wordlist1 = a1.split()
    wordlist2 = a2.split()   
    for i in wordlist1:
        if i in wordlist2:
            print(i)
        else:
            print('No common word.')
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sen1 = (input("Input first sentence: ").split(" "))
sen2 = (input("input second sentence: ").split(" "))
print(list(set(sen1).intersection(sen2)))
```